# Android check spaces in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a problem regarding Edit Text in Android.

I have a field named Username :

I want that whenever someone writes a username with a space e.g "Gaurav Arora". Then it should raise a toast or error on the login button press.

I did in this way - I simply stopped the effect of space bar with the help of a text watcher as-

```
public static TextWatcher getNameTextWatcher(final TextView agrTextView) {
        TextWatcher mTextWatcherName = new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                String result = agrTextView.getText().toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
                if (!agrTextView.getText().toString().equals(result)) {
                    agrTextView.setText(result);
                }

}
}
```

But this has not solved my purpose. I just want to implement whenever the person uses a username with space it should accept the space but on the press of login button it should raise a toast

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you check if there is space in the text on the button click instead?

Comment: Yes i want to check on the login button that if edittext has any spaces. How can I check?

Comment: if(string.indexOf(" ") != -1)Toast(...)

Comment: u can try with string.contains(" ") its Boolean method

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just check if your edit text contains blank space or not.

Use the following code in the `onClick()` event of the Button.

```
 if (agrTextView.getText().toString().contains(" ")) {
     agrTextView.setError("No Spaces Allowed");
     Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "No Spaces Allowed", 5000).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this..

```
     btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String result = agrTextView.getText().toString();
             if(result.contains ("\\s"))
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Space ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply do this:

```
TextView.getText().toString().contains(" ");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 String question = txtNote.getText().toString();
 if(question.trim().length() > 0){
    Log.i("LOG", "Has value");
 }else{
    Log.i("LOG", "don't has value");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

use **trim()** method to remove all spaces and then **check for empty**

```
if ( !edtText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
  //the EditText is not Empty
}
```

Comment: read the question carefully before posting an irrelative answer. Also in case you haven't checked out the base steps for a helpful post , please see : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can block entering space bar in username, or can give toast or snack on entering space in username .

Can refer this link might be helpful for you  [Block entering space in edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54397295/5886712).

Let me know if any concern.