# EditText not adding space after word swiped in

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, swipe, android-alertdialog

I have an android phone using googles keyboard. On any EditText field in any other app if I use the swipe method to enter text in, it adds a space after each word. However, I have written my own app and when I use the swipe method to enter text on my EditText field it does NOT add a space sothewordsbleedtogether. This is very annoying.

I have an AlertDialog with a linear view added. On that linear view there is a text EditText. Here is my code to create the EditText and add it to the view:

```
final EditText titleBox = new EditText(this);
titleBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT |
    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES |
    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_SHORT_MESSAGE);
titleBox.setHint("Title");
layout.addView(titleBox);
```

Any ideas why its not adding spaces in between my words?

This was marked as a possible duplicate, but that question was about not allowing the first character to be a space....Im asking about allowing a space after words that are entered via a keyboard swipe.

**Update**

Here is the entire method of similar page, its having the same issue, its slightly less complex then the initial page I was troubleshooting. This one doesn't even have a LinearLayout associated:

```
private void addBudget(final Budget budget) {
EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
        taskEditText.setId(R.id.add_budget_text);
             taskEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);

String dialogTitle = "Add budget";
final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(dialogTitle)
                .setMessage("What do you want to call this budget?")
                .setView(taskEditText)
                .setPositiveButton("Save", new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // final String task = ;
                        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();


                        Budget lBudget = new Budget();
                        if (budget != null) {
                            lBudget = budget;
                        }
                        EditText taskEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_budget_text);
                        lBudget.title = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());

                        // Init custom budget object //new Budget(){{ title=task; id = budgetID;}}
                        int retId = mHelper.saveBudget(db, lBudget);

                        db.close();
                        int retRow = updateUI(retId);
                        mTaskListView.smoothScrollToPosition(retRow);

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create();
// Handle done on soft keyboard
        taskEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                int result = actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION;
                if (result == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        dialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: what do you meant by swipe text in?

Comment: i think you can check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/19514175/5319409 hope it helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android EditText Space Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511075/android-edittext-space-validation)

Comment: By swipe i mean, you can either tap keys, or use a swiping motion to enter text into a field. Of course you can manually type a space key, but when swiping it takes care of the spaces in between the words for you. In my app swiping does not enter the space key.

Comment: @AndrewIndayang this is not a duplicate. That linked question was trying to not allow spaces as the first character being entered. This is almost the opposite. I need to allow spaces to be added in between words that are entered using a swiping motion on the google keyboard. Every other app ive tried on my phone works, but i can get it to work in my own app.

Answer (score 1):

I didnt know if you got solved, i just had the same problem today and found a way to solve it.

I saw a "extrange" performance of the swipe, sometimes it showed the "blankspace" and sometimes not.

The way i found to check if it was shown and if it didnt, add it, was this:

```
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            checkCancel();
            int compare = count-before;
            if(compare>1){
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                String lastChar = (text.substring(text.length()-1,text.length()));
                if(!lastChar.equals(" ")){
                    String plus = text+" ";
                    editText.setText(plus);
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        } );
```

You can see, onTextChanged can use the variables "before" and "count" and if the compare (difference between last word and current one) is more than 1, it's a word entered by Swipe. Then you can check if the "blankspace" is shown, and if not, just add it and perfom anything you want with it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this? Add the filter into the editText. I used it for enter code on my app.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int end, Spanned spanned, int start, int end {
           if(charSequence.equals("")){
                return charSequence;
           }
           if(charSequence.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){
                return charSequence;
           }
           return "";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didnt have any effect. I also tried to change the EditText to not be final, that didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

So I uninstalled the google keyboard and reinstalled and I changed the build to release. One of those two things fixed it.

Comment: So have you try on other phone?

Comment: yes, on my wifes, however that was a fresh install of the keyboard, and an install off the marketplace. Thats what inspired my course of action