# Regex with all special symbols

Tags: android, regex

I need regex that will allow only Latin characters, digits and all other symbols(but not whitespace)

thanks!

UPDATE:

```
private boolean loginPassHasCorrectSymbols(String input){
        if (input.matches("[A-Za-z0-9\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\>\=\?\@\[\]\{\}\\\^\_\`\~]+$")){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: When you say "special symbols", do you mean all of the [basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin_script) characters that aren't alphanumeric characters?

Comment: all symbols that can be typed from keyboard, but i think you are right )

Comment: If you need to protect just Cyrillic letters, why not use [`(?U)^[^\\s\\p{IsCyrillic}]*$`](http://ideone.com/NieW6x)? Try `input.matches("(?U)[^\\s\\p{IsCyrillic}]*")`.

Comment: @stribizhev Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 3:
    (?U)[^\s\p{IsCyrillic}]*

Comment: @stribizhev U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR ((

Comment: Were you also hoping to capture whitespace also? The regex I gave you includes almost everything except for whitespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope I got them all.

```
"[A-Za-z0-9\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\>\=\?\@\[\]\{\}\\\\\^\_\`\~]+$"
```

Edit: I forgot that in Java, the regexes are also strings, so you need to actually escape each `\` given in the string using another `\`. I hope I didn't miss any now.

```
"[A-Za-z0-9\\!\\\"\\#\\$\\%\\&\\'\\(\\)\\*\\+\\,\\-\\.\\/\\:\\;\\<\\>\\=\\?\\@\\[\\]\\{\\}\\\\\\^\\_\\`\\~]+$"
```

Comment: @LeoCHan: You know Python re better I guess, right? You do not need `$`.

Comment: @stribizhev I imagine I'm fairly decent in both Java and Python. Java was my first after all :) But in the original post, the OP had a `$` at the end of his original regex which made me assume he wanted a `$` to mark the end of a line.

Comment: @LudoBagman I just added more backslashes hoping I escaped everything correctly.

Comment: without symbol " here \\!\\" - it works )
how can I add this symbol?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but check if adding more backslashes will work, making it `\\!\\\"`. So for the `\\\"`, you have 2 backslashes to get one `\\` and another backslash to get `"`. If it works, tell me so I can update my answer please.

Comment: The regex is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

How about everything not a whitespace?

```
"^\S+$"
```

Comment: nope )
cos, i need in such case protect cyrillic symbols )

Comment: Hmm, Cyrillic wasn't part of the requirement as I grokked it. I have no experience with that but knowledge thereof :). You might get something out of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716609/how-to-match-cyrillic-characters-with-a-regular-expression) but I don't even know how to test it myself .... Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it works for me .

Either you can block **whitespace** by mentioning it on Edittext, or you can block on editetext.addtextChangeListner too by pragmatically .

**1>**

```
android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,*,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,_,-"
```

**2>**

```
etNewPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (etNewPassword.getText().toString().contains(" ")) {
                    etNewPassword.setText(etNewPassword.getText().toString().replace(" ", ""));
                    int iLength = etNewPassword.getText().toString().length();
                    etNewPassword.setSelection(iLength);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

For find any symbol except whitespace, you can use this code. I hope you find it useful

```
public static boolean hasAnySymbolExceptWhitespace(String string){
    return Pattern.matches("(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9] ).*", string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Smooth Kotlin solution which allows English letters with some default symbols. Cyrillic or any other language symbols won't be allowed.

```
//Allows english with usual symbols 
private fun hasNonAllowedSymbols(input: String) : Boolean {
    val regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\s-#,/~`'!@$%^&*()_+={}|;<>.?:\"\\[\\]\\\\]*"
    val pattern = Pattern.compile(regex)
    return !pattern.matcher(input).matches()
}
```